# Dropdown no modal não enxerga scope do controller Angular JS 1.5

Tags: angularjs, modal, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

bom dia.

O problema é o seguinte, tenho uma página de feed de notícias e dentro dela uso um Modal [Angular UI - Modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
para mostrar as informações de um post em específico. Até ai tudo tranquilo, as informações e funções que eu declaro dentro do controller do modal enxergam as informações, porém, dentro deste modal eu tenho um DropDown com duas opções, "Excluir" e "Editar".

**DropDown**

```
<div class="dropdown menu-feed">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
 </span>
 <div class="dropdown-menu">                        
  <li><a class="dropdown-item" ng-click="vm.deleteComment()">Excluir</a></li>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Controller Modal**

```
            $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: 'templates/feed/modal/modalPost.html',
            windowClass: 'post-modal',
            size: 'lg',
            controller: function ($uibModalInstance) {
            var vm = this;    
            vm.deleteComment = deleteComment;
            function deleteComment(){
               console.log('Aqui estou sendo chamado dentro do dropdown');
            }
            },controllerAs:'vm'
            });
```

Porém, nenhuma função é chamada, nem as funções que estão dentro do modal ( Ao qual eu omiti elas aqui para melhorar a visualização do problema).

Testei a variável {{ $index }} dentro do modal e eu tenho o retorno de qual scope eu estou, porém quando insiro dentro do "li" no dropdown eu não tenho nenhum scope vinculado.

Alguma dica de como proceder?

Answer (score 2):

Passe a referência do escopo atual para o uibModal:

```
$uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: 'templates/feed/modal/modalPost.html',
    scope: $scope, //referência
    [...]
```

Comment: Quando eu declaro o $scope eu chamo minha função na sem o $scope certo?
Ex: 
ng-click="deleteComment()"

Acrescentei o $scope no meu modal, porém de nada adiantou, ele continua não enxergando o escopo.

Comment: @MikaelHadler se você está executando este código dentro de um controller, você pode injetar o serviço $scope e passá-lo como referência.

Comment: Exatamente, estou utilizando ele dentro de outro controller, fiz os dois teste, injetei o $scope no meu controller superior ao controller do modal para testar, passei na função do modal e passei o $scope nas propriedades do modal, sem sucesso.

Retirei o $scope do modal superior a ele e coloquei o "scope: $scope" na propriedade do modal, passei o $scope como parametro da function do modal e também nada.

Comment: Quando passo a propriedade do scope: $scope nas propriedades do modal e passo $scope na função do controller, tenho o retorno de que o $scope não foi definido. 

Sendo assim eu tentei passar o $scope no $inject do meu controller superior ao modal para ele ser definido, passando o $scope como propriedade do modal e injetando na função, mas também não tive sucesso.

Comment: Problema resolvido, consegui fazer o $scope funcionar passando pela propriedade do modal e injetando na função do controller.